# Values double have in C

Tags: c, variables, double

Which numbers can a double type contain? (in C language)
I was trying to find the numbers that double can contain in c.
I know that a float can contain numbers between -10^38

Comment: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) you can have it here... your ans is 2.3E-308 to 1.7E+308

Comment: I recommend you read a little about numerical analysis

Comment: I wonder if that information can be found on the internet somewhere.

Comment: See ISO 9899:2011 §5.2.4.2.2 for more details.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Sure: by asking instead of searching oneself. Isn't SO "on  the internet"? (Doing research on your own is a diminishing ability)

Comment: Hmm.. Google says a double is 8 bytes, so there can be 2^64 discrete values. Given a few odd values maybe taken up to represent NaN, +,- infinity etc, I guess '2^64 less a tiny bit' is as good an answer as any,,

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sure it can, but Googling the range does not help your sockpuppets and/or voting rings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a `double` is *usually* an IEEE double.  I don't know if this is required by the standard, but these days it would be unusual for it to be something else.  Here's some info on double precision formats, particularly IEEE:  [double-precision floating point formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: 1) No, it is not required by the standard. But the standard encourages IEC 60559 Floating point. However, there are a lot of implementations which are not compatible, mostly for embedded systems, but still widely used.

Comment: @Olaf Ah, that makes sense.  I was thinking in terms of desktop computers and servers.